What does "over the grind" means?
I searched on Google and YouTube, but I didn't find any results about "over the grind" at all. And I'm not sure what it means. However, I found "grind (down)" which is perhaps a synonym (but again, I'm not sure and would like clarification.) Finally, the example I saw from an Australian newspaper

if you're over the grind of your 9 to 5 job and longing for an adventure, this story might just be for you!


@Xanne Please consider expanding the comment into an answer.

“Over the grind” has no meaning; it’s not a phrase.
The phrasal verb here is “to get over [something]”, where something is a difficulty or a loss or a disappointment, such as a poor job evaluation, the breakup of a relationship, a death in the family, and the like.
In this sentence it’s “the grind of your 9 to 5 job,” which you perhaps used to like but no longer do.  Thus you may be ready for something more adventurous.

Over

no longer interested in or concerned about (someone or something)

MW
Grind

DRUDGE

MW
Drudge

to do hard, menial, or monotonous work

MW
9-5 (nine-to-five)

a job with regular daytime hours

Mw
The intended parsing can be paraphrased as being no longer interested in the menial work of your job.
